# Add a custom function in a vendor repository

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using CCDNForum's ForumBundle (the bundle itself is not relevant, my question isn't related to this bundle specifically but is more general) in my Symfony website, and I want to customize it, so naturally I created a AcmeForumBundle whose parent is CCDNForumForumBundle. The only thing I want to change is to add a new custom function in let say the CategoryRepository associated to the Category entity.

So I created a CategoryRepository.php in my AcmeForumBundle extending the CategoryRepository.php of CCDNForum, and this is not sufficient because the default repository of the Category entity is CCDNForum's CategoryRepository.

The next thing I did was to create a new AcmeForumBundle Category entity extending CCDNForum's Category entity, changing of course the default associated repository

```
namespace Acme\ForumBundle\Entity;

use CCDNForum\ForumBundle\Entity\Category as BaseCategory;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection as ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\ForumBundle\Repository\CategoryRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="CC_Forum_Category")
 */
class Category extends BaseCategory
{
}
```

I added the @ORM\Table line because I had an SQL error "acme_category" table not found. The class is of course empty as I have nothing to change in the entity.

Using this code everything works fine, I added my custom function in the CategoryRepository without problem, but the problem comes when I want to update the database schema. I have the error when running php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException]
The table with name 'acme.cc_forum_category' already exists.
```

which I can understand since CCDNForum's Category entity and my Acme Category entity are using the same table (the C_Forum_Category table).

My question is: am I doing all this right ? Isn't there a simpler way to add a custom function in a vendor repository ?

Thanks!

Comment: Your doctrine needs to have some kind of inheritance relation specified.  I don't have enough details for a full answer until I get to work on Monday.

Comment: Yes, but since the original entity is in a vendor bundle, I can't add any inheritance mappings at all (eg @InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")), can I ?

Comment: You might need mapped superclass instead.

Comment: Yeah, but I have the same problem: I can't add a @MappedSuperclass to the base entity since it's in a vendor bundle.